# mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
require_once("connect.php");

$login1 = $_POST['email'];
$password1 = $_POST['password'];
$select = "SELECT id FROM loginregistration WHERE login ='$login1', password   ='$password1'";
$sql = mysqli_query($con,$select);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
?>`
```

it seems that my mysqli_query doesn't work ,what should i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_fetch\_array()/mysqli\_fetch\_assoc()/mysqli\_fetch\_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource or mysqli\_result, boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysqli-fetch-array-mysqli-fetch-assoc-mysqli-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1)

Comment: The first thing you should do is fix the SQL injection vulnerability (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)  That way you're actually controlling what query you execute instead of letting the user define their own query.  The next thing you should do is check for errors after executing any query, never assume it was successful.  The database is telling you what the problem is, but this code ignores that error message.

Comment: use concatenate and remove comma near password $select = "SELECT id FROM loginregistration WHERE login ='".$login1."' and  password ='".$password1."'";

Comment: I disagree with David... The FIRST thing you should do is **stop storing passwords in plain text**!!! Spend some time researching how to manage login credentials securely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use AND insted of comma (,) in query near password  that's why query returning false and throw that error

```
$select = "SELECT id FROM loginregistration WHERE login ='".$login1."' and password ='".$password1."'";
```

UPDATE 1

if query fail it return false . so you can use mysqli_error($con); to know the error

```
    <?php
    require_once("connect.php");

    $login1 = $_POST['email'];
    $password1 = $_POST['password'];
    $select = "SELECT id FROM loginregistration WHERE login ='".$login1."' AND password   ='".$password1."'";
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,$select);

    if($sql === FALSE) { 
        die(mysqli_error($con)); // better error handling
    }

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
    ?>
```